# Prove that there exists no surjection between $X\rightarrow P(X)$ -Proof question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

There is a hint that I shound take an arbitrary function $F:X\rightarrow P(X)$ and show that the subset $\{ x\in X|x\notin F(x) \}$ is not an element of $F(X)$. I don't know how one could came up with something like that what was the Intuition behind that and how do we even know that such a subset even *exists*?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127149/proof-detail-concerning-bijection-between-a-set-and-its-power-set

Comment: I don't think the OP has trouble understanding the proof. What he wants is too understand how one conjures up such a set out of nothing. What is the intuition behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an arbitrary function $F:X\to P(X)$, you want to produce a subset $Z$ of $X$ that is not in $F(X)$; I'll try to explain how one might guess the $Z$ that seemed to be invented magically and just happened to work.

The desired property of $Z$, namely $Z\notin F(X)$, means that, for each $x\in X$, we have $Z\neq F(x)$. That, in turn, means that, for each $x\in X$, there is some $y\in X$ "witnessing that $Z\neq F(x)$", by which I mean that either $y\in Z$ but $y\notin F(x)$ or else $y\notin Z$ but $y\in F(x)$.

When constructing $Z$, we have to make sure that, for each $x\in X$, there is some $y\in X$ as described in the previous paragraph. We have considerable freedom as to which $y$ we should use to do this job; we only have to make sure that each $x$ gets at least one appropriate $y$.

Now comes the (only?) clever idea in the construction: For each $x$, I'll choose, as the associated $y$, the simplest choice that comes to mind, namely $x$ itself.  (I'll comment later on what would happen if we made different choices here.)  So we want that, for each $x\in X$, either $x\in Z$ but $x\notin F(x)$ or else $x\notin Z$ but $x\in F(x)$.  That says exactly that $Z=\{x\in X:x\notin F(x)\}$.  So that's where the set in your hint came from.

What if I had chosen, for various (perhaps all) $x$'s, some $y$ other than $x$ itself?  Well, if I chose the same $y$ for two different $x$'s, say $x_1$ and $x_2$, then I might get into trouble. Namely, if $y\in F(x_1)$ and $y\notin F(x_2)$, then I'll want $y\notin Z$ (for the sake of $x_1$) and $y\in Z$ (for the sake of $x_2$), and so there won't be any suitable $Z$.  So I'd better make sure I pick different $y$'s for different $x$'s.  In other words, the function $x\mapsto y$ should be one-to-one.  But that's all that I need to watch out for. Given any one-to-one function $w:X\to X$, there will exist a $Z$ such that, for each $x\in X$, $w(x)$ serves as the desired $y$ above.  In other words, there is $Z\subseteq X$ such that, for all $x\in X$, we have $w(x)\in Z\iff w(x)\notin F(x)$.  (If $w$ is not surjective, then there will be more than one such $Z$ because nothing constrains $Z$ outside the range of $w$.)

Comment: How can you know that $x\mapsto y$ is one-to-one is really the only restriction ? Maybe there exists a restriction which cancels out the identity map

Comment: @New2Math You know things like that by proving them. Assuming that $w:X\to X$ is one-to-one and setting $Z=\{u\in\text{Range}(w):u\notin F(w^{-1}(u))\}$, prove that $Z\notin\text{Range}(F)$ by checking that, for every $x\in Z$, we have $w(x)\in Z\iff w(x)\notin F(x)$.

Comment: You said you might get into Trouble if the function is not injective does it mean if I pick a function that is not injective but I make sure that Elements with the same Image also have the same behaviour the function would be acceptable?

Comment: @New2Math That depends on what you mean by "the same behaviour". The sentence in my answer that begins "Namely ..." (right after the sentence about getting into trouble) describes exactly the trouble that could arise. As long as you avoid that situation, the argument will still work.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I didnot understand your second paragraph. Why you introduced y in it ? From where did it come ?

Comment: @J.Deff The $y$ in the second paragraph comes from the general fact that two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements. So $Z\neq F(x)$ if and only if there is something that is an element of one of $Z$ and $F(x)$ but not an element of the other. That something is what I called $y$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass i say diagonal argument to prove this one. its quite intuitive to understand By MIT , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dj1ogUwTEM

Comment: @AndreasBlass i didnot understand last 4 lines of last paragraph. Given any one to one function w ....

Comment: @J.Deff I agree that the diagonal argument is clear; it is apparetnly not so intuitive, since the whole point of this question was to intuitively motivate it. If it's already intuitive for you, then you need neither this question nor my answer. As for those last 4 lines, I've re-read them, and I don't see what you might not understand there, especially if you also look at my first comment in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

See [Axiom schema of Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) : given a set (in this case $X$), the axiom states that every subset that we can "specify" by way of a suitable formula exists.

The intuition is quite simple. Consider an $a ∈ X$ whatever: either $a ∈ F(a)$ or not.

If not, put it into the new defined set. At the end, either the new set will be empty (in which case is a subset of $X$) or not: in which case is "made of" elements of $X$, and again is a subset of $X$.

Consider the simple example of $F : X → \mathcal P(X)$ such that $F(a) = \{ a \}, for each $a ∈ X$.

Obviously : $a ∈ \{ a \} = F(a)$ and thus : $Y = \{ x ∈ X \mid x ∉ F(x) \} = \emptyset$.

But in the above example $F$ is "arbitrary"; thus, in principle we may have $a ∉ F(a)$ for some (maybe none) $a ∈ X$.

---

The construction is the core of the fundamental [Cantor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), stating that the set of all subsets of a set $A$ has a strictly greater cardinality than $A$ itself.