# Understanding Proof that there is no Onto function between set and its power set

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

[image]

I am having hard time understanding the proof that there is no onto function from set A to its power set. In the proof author has constructed the set B = {$a \in A : a \notin f(a)$}. I have taken few sets and constructed functions but i am not able to get the intuition behind construction of set B , i mean to say how should we know that set B has to be constructed in this way

Thanks

Comment: Can you please write the proof. From just that set it is not easy to see what the author intends by it. It would make it easier for people to understand.

Comment: It is not clear what the image and pre-image of the set $f$ is.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Edited

Comment: Have you searched the site? There are *so many* questions on Cantor's theorem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you help me which the second patragraph of the answer here by Andreas...... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116626/prove-that-there-exists-no-surjection-between-x-rightarrow-px-proof-questio?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

It is the beautiful idea of the proof to look at exactly this set $B$. Don't mind when you think you might not have had this idea.

We have to show that no function $f:\>A\to{\cal P}(A)$ can be surjective. Cantor's idea is to produce for any such $f:\>A\to{\cal P}(A)$  a set $B_f\in {\cal P}(A)$ that does not occur as function value $f(a)$ for some $a\in A$. The set $B_f$ he proposes is
$$B_f:=\bigl\{a\in A\bigm| a\notin f(a)\bigr\}\ .$$
It is then an exercise for the reader to prove that $B_f\ne f(a)$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: In understand the proof but not why and how the idea of set B

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks for your post